# Representing two objects calling each other in a sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have an object **A** of type **TypeA** which calls an object **B** of type **TypeB**. During the call, **B** is calling **A**.

In the tool which I'm using to draw the sequence diagram, the arrows which represent the calls only go from left to right (I can't say if it is an **UML** restriction, or a tool restriction).

If it is an **UML** restriction, how is the described situation supposed to be drawn?

Comment: Jim's answer shows the right use. You should tell which tool you are using so maybe someone can help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tool is broken if messages can only flow from left to right. Sounds like you need a better tool. Having a message flow from right to left is allowed in UML itself. In fact, here's an example in [MagicDraw](http://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw.html) for you.

**Class diagram:**

[image]

**Sequence Diagram:**

[image]

Notice how `b` is making a call back to `a` and how the lifeline is nested on `a`.

Comment: This is a good answer, well explained. One detail is not correct, though: According to UML it is not allowed to show sequence numbers on messages in sequence diagrams. So-called sequence expressions are only allowed in communication diagrams.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl: Thanks for the positive feedback. I'll check out the 2.5 spec shortly. I believe MagicDraw allows suppression of these numbers, so I'll update the diagram if I find it is indeed illegal UML.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl: I just checked the UML 2.5 spec. I found an example with message numbering in Figure 17.10, Example showing GeneralOrdering in a sequence diagram.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I think the notation for messages is specified in 17.4.4.1, which does not include the sequence expressions. The sequence expressions are defined only in 17.9.1.3, which is part of the chapter about communication diagrams. So unless I'm overlooking something, I think the numbering in Figure 17.10 must be a mistake in the spec.